# Tkinter : Can't put border color (TicTacToe game)

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, label, frame

I want to display a green color on each side of the winning boxes. I'm trying to use the `highlightbackground` and the `highlightcolor` , but it seems to not working.

However the `foreground` seems to work.

There is my code :

Creating the frame and label

```
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        con_frame = tk.Frame(top_frame, bg=None,
                             highlightbackground="grey",
                             highlightcolor="grey",
                             relief="solid",
                             highlightthickness=3)
        lbl = tk.Label(con_frame, text="",
                       height=2, width=5,
                       bg="#22a7f0",
                       font="Helvetica 45 bold",
                       bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        lbl.grid(sticky='nsew')
        lbl.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, xy=[x, y]: get_cordinate(xy))
        con_frame.grid(row=x, column=y, padx=2, pady=2)

        dict_labels = {"xy": [x, y], "symbol": "", "label": lbl, "ticked": False}
        list_labels.append(dict_labels)
```

Function check row

```
def check_row():
    list_symbols = []
    list_labels_temp = []
    winner = False
    win_symbol = ""
    for i in range(len(list_labels)):
        list_symbols.append(list_labels[i]["symbol"])
        list_labels_temp.append(list_labels[i])
        if (i + 1) % 3 == 0:
            if list_symbols[0] == list_symbols[1] == list_symbols[2]:
                if list_symbols[0] != "":
                    winner = True
                    win_symbol = list_symbols[0]

                    list_labels_temp[0]["label"].config(foreground="#00e640", highlightbackground="green",
                                                        highlightcolor="green", highlightthickness=2)
                    list_labels_temp[1]["label"].config(foreground="#00e640", highlightbackground="green",
                                                        highlightcolor="green", highlightthickness=2)
                    list_labels_temp[2]["label"].config(foreground="#00e640", highlightbackground="green",
                                                        highlightcolor="green", highlightthickness=2)

            list_symbols = []
            list_labels_temp = []

    return [winner, win_symbol]
```

I struggle with that for a few days, but i can't find the solution....

Thanks for the help.[image]

Comment: Post the code how to create those labels as well.

Comment: Ok , I just updated my post with it.

Comment: Try give some padding between the `con_frame` and the label, and use the frame background color to simulate the border.  Then you can change the frame background color to simulate the effect you want.